# how to fix "beacon evt is currently scheduled" error while sceduling selfMsgs in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to implement a recurrent timer to achieve this I used self msg did the following :

```
void rsuApp::initialize(int stage) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
   if (stage == 0) {
        event = new cMessage("event");
        EV << "Scheduling first send to t=5.0s\n";
        scheduleAt(10, event);
    }
}
```

and I reschedule the self msg in the handleSelfMsg() function like this

```
void rsuApp::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(msg);
    if(msg==event){
        EV<<"self message receives";
        scheduleAt(simTime()+10, event);
    }
}
```

but during simulation i get the following error :

```
scheduleAt(): Message (omnetpp::cMessage)beacon evt is currently scheduled,
 use cancelEvent() before rescheduling -- in module (rsuApp)
 trackingNetwork.rsu[0].appl (id=8), at t=20s, event #453
```

i don't understand why do i get this error because i didn't schedule any beacon event and I rescheduled the self message in the handleSelfMsg() function which means after it was received so i don't understand why do i get this error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I think it is because the reschedule of the event cMessage is called again before the end of the timer.
So, to solve it just add cancelEvent(event); before the reschedule.
One more thing, in the initialize() you should add your timer value to the current simTime() in the scheduleAt(), just like you did in the handleSelfMsg().